# Hyper-V: There was an error during the move: operation is not supported

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Trying to Migrate VMs off a server to another Hyper-V server temporarily due to a hardware failure but I keep getting this message. I don't see anything in the event viewer and I've checked the CPU option to move the VM.

Host machine is a 2016 machine and the other I am moving to is a 2012r2. Could that be the issue?

Update due to questions:
The 2012r2 machines are running v5 VMs and the 2016 is running v8 VMs.

[image]

Comment: Which configuration version are you using? If you have a v8 VM - that is a 2016 feature, obviously it can not be moved.

Comment: I'll have to check. Not sure how to check at the top of my head. Wasn't aware there were versions of VMs.

Comment: Not VM's - Configurations. They moved to binary coding from XML in 2016. It was all over the readme - never bothered to read it?

Comment: I probably missed it. It's hard to stay on top of every little change when you work DevOps and SysOps along with just about every hyperviser product. Not actually lucky enough to work at a big company in a dedicated department specializing in one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of virtual Machines are you running?

VMs running versions only supported by server 2016 cannot run on server 2012R2. to check your version:

1. On the Windows desktop, click the Start button and type any part of the name Windows PowerShell.
2. Right-click Windows PowerShell and select Run as Administrator.
3. Use the Get-VM cmdlet. Run the following command to get the versions of your virtual machines.
   Get-VM * | Format-Table Name, Version

You can also see the configuration version in Hyper-V Manager by selecting the virtual machine and looking at the Summary tab.

The following table shows which virtual machine configuration versions are supported by Hyper-V hosts that run on specific versions of Windows operating systems.

- Windows Server 2016 8.0, 7.1, 7.0, 6.2, 5.0
- Windows 10 Anniversary Update 8.0, 7.1, 7.0, 6.2, 5.0
- Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 7.1, 7.0, 6.2, 5.0
- Windows 10 build 10565 or later 7.0, 6.2, 5.0
- Windows 10 builds earlier than 10565 6.2, 5.0
- Windows Server 2012 R2 5.0
- Windows 8.1 5.0

Comment: Looks like it is a version issue. Wasn't aware VMs had versions.